# Fire event only after the user has paused for a certain length of time?

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I'm using C#, .NET 3.1. In my app, I have an IntegerUpDown control whose value property is databound to a property in the UCs codebehind. If this property hits 0 I want to invoke an event. My current implementation looks like this:

```
private int prop;

public int Prop
{
    get
    {
        return prop;
    }

    set
    {
        prop = value;

        if (prop == 0)
        {
            // invoke event
        }
    }
}
```

The Problem I have with this is that every time the user clicks the arrows of the IntegerUpDown-Control my code checks if the value is 0. My question is if there is a way to invoke the event sort of "intelligently". What I mean by that is, that the event would, for example, only be invoked if the user hasnt pressed the arrow for the last 2 seconds, so as to indicate that he is finished adjusting the value.

I'm also wondering if I should even worry about it since I don't how much the program would actually be slowed down by such a thing. If someone has any input on that I'd also greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Define your binding as `{Binding Prop, Delay=2000}`.

Comment: The terminology you are looking for is called *Debouncing*

Comment: I don't know wpf, so maybe adding a delay is helpful (although 2 seconds can be a long time to wait for the UI to respond). Is the code that checks if the value is `0` really causing a problem? That's a relatively really fast operation that wouldn't normally be a problem.

Comment: It's possible that doing the assignment and comparing the result in the `if` condition might be a tiny bit faster (i.e.: `if ((prop = value) == 0)`), but I'm not at a computer where I can compare the generated the IL right now.

Comment: Are you actually seeing some sort of a problem? If not then I would suggest you're prematurely optimising against something isn't there. I'm not so sure this is debouncing you're describing. If the user reduces the value to 1. Stops for 1 or 2 seconds. Then they hit the down arrrow. Do you really not want to run the event?

Comment: You've not explained what this event does or is. Should it really be an event? I would have thought more significant is maybe whether that event already ran or is running. Maybe you should be flagging one or both of these instead. Or maybe you should disable the control entirely and stop input once a state is reached.

Comment: As already suggested: use [Binding.Delay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingbase.delay?view=netcore-3.1#remarks).

Comment: While you could delay as suggested, a simple int value check shouldn't be costly under normal conditions. A delay may actually be more costly than a simple int comparison as it's has to be reset with every click and monitored for lapsing (but I'm not sure about that).

Comment: @Andy im asking this question moreso from a theoretical standpoint. The app in question is something im doing privately so probably isn't gonna experience such heavy traffic that something like this actually matters but im trying to learn how to optimize and write clean code so i usually look for ways to do something "the right way" and since I didn't find something on this topic on the interwebs i decided to post here

Comment: @MichaelRandall Yeah that's what I was looking for, thanks a lot.